# Check if mail send by cakephp is sent or not and mail address is not valid

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How can we test  by `$email->send()` function if mail sent or not and email address is valid

I have tried.

```
   try {
        $email->send();

        return true;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {

        return false;
    }
```

But mail is sent and it  doesn't return any error if mail is send and mail address is valid.

How can we get response from server if mail is received by user or not and how can we check mail address is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

just check if the it returns true or not.

```
if($email->send())//if mail has been sent.
{
   return true;
}
```

You can read the class   Validation::email() for email validation.

Comment: yes it returns true even if mail is not send to receiver. because email->send() function returns only content send in mail.